# max_allowed_packet after mysql restart

Tags: mysql, max-connections

I want to set `max_allowed_packet` parameter in runtime. The

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 16777216
```

works for new connections, but after database server restart, it has previous value. Can value of the `max_allowed_packet` in runtime for new connection and restart of database server will not affect this value?

Thank you.

Comment: set the value again globally and add the new value in config file so after restart it comes back to what you want or you can use init_file and set the value of your need in it as it would be read at instance start-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting in the command line are not persisted anywhere. Therefore after a restart it resets to default or picks up the value from the config file.

Put the following line into your my.cnf file under the [mysqld] section:

```
max_allowed_packet = 16777216
```

About how to find what file is used you can find some resources here on stack exchange as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location